# php echo statement li can't be loaded

Tags: php

I'm new to php and i need help with this code, because i get "HTTP-fout 500 (Internal Server Error):" when i try to load it. could someone post the whole good code. thanks.

```
      <?php
    session_start();


    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $notifications[] = 'Login failed! Please provide a username and password.';
   }

       if(count($notifications) == 0) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db33936_axe;host=mysql12-int.cp.hostnet.nl',   
    'u33936_mick', '123');

        $sql = "SELECT username, verified FROM users WHERE username = :username AND    
    password = :password";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array(
            ':username'    => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => md5($_POST['password'])
        ));

        $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($result) {
            // Set session details and redirect user to members page
            session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['username']=':username';
        $_SESSION['password']=':password';

            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            $notifications[] = "Username or Password incorrect.";
        }
```

Comment: your quotes need fixing `echo "<li id="`  <- string ended here! use \" to escape your quotes inside strings

Comment: Why is there a `</style>` here?  Also, when pasting code, don't put 4 new lines between every line of code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatched quotes. Try this:

```
echo "<li id='login'>
```

And

```
<a id='login-trigger' href='#'>
```

Alternatively, you can escape them like this:

```
<a id=\"login-trigger\" href=\"#\">
```

Or simply change the double quotes at the start and end of your `echo` to single quotes.
Do this for all of your quotes inside the `echo` statement.

Comment: For long chunks of HTML inside PHP code, you can also use HEREDOC, too.

Comment: @andrewsi +1 good point

Answer (score 0):

The double-quotes " you use for your echo statement are closed by those you use in it for your html tags, put backslashes before every " like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"#\">link</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quote that long string with single quotes like this:

```
echo '<li id="login">
    ...
</li>';
```